# Is there a numpy/scipy function to calculate outbound penalty?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize

In my minimization problem, all bounded minimize methods, such as 'L-BFGS-B', 'TNC' do not converge, but 'Nelder-Mead' converged very good. So I prefer to use 'Nelder-Mead', with modified minimize function, like this:

```
def outbound_penalty(x, bounds):
    o1 = (bounds[:, 0]-x).max()
    o2 = (x-bounds[:, 1]).max()
    outbound = max(o1, o2, 0)
    rez = 100500*outbound

def bounded_fun(x, bounds):
    return fun(x) + outbound_penalty(x, bounds)
```

x is numpy array shape (4), bounds has shape (2, 4), bounds[0] is bottom borders, bounds[1] - top borders.
It is surprisingly not as fast as I expected. At 4*10^6 calls it takes 40 seconds own time on CPU.
Surely I memoized that. But I have to ask. Are there some very optimized functions in numpy/scipy, that can I use to construct outbound penalties?

```
sss = np.zeros((2, 1000))
sss[0] = np.random.uniform(-100, 300, 1000)
sss[1] = np.random.uniform(-100, 300, 1000)
smpls = sss.T

bnd = np.array([[0, 100+np.random.randint(100)], [0, 100+np.random.randint(100)]])
np_bounds = np.array(bnd)

def outbound_penalty(x, bs):
    o1 = (bs[:, 0] - x).max()
    o2 = (x - bs[:, 1]).max()
    outbound = max(o1, o2, 0)
    return 1000000 * outbound

def outbound_penalty_fast(x, bs):
    o1 = (bs[:, 0, None] - x).max(axis=0)
    o2 = (x - bs[:, 1, None]).max(axis=0)
    outbound = np.clip(np.maximum(o1, o2), a_max=None, a_min=0)
    return 1000000 * outbound

%timeit [outbound_penalty(x, np_bounds) for x in smpls]
22.6 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit [outbound_penalty_fast(x, np_bounds) for x in smpls]
68.6 ms ± 1.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit outbound_penalty(smpls[0], np_bounds)
22.5 µs ± 109 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit outbound_penalty_fast(smpls[0], np_bounds)
68.2 µs ± 1.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This version of outbound_penalty_fast returns single float point number, as expected by caller:

```
def outbound_penalty_fast(x, bs):
    o1 = (bs[:, 0, None] - x).max(axis=0)
    o2 = (x - bs[:, 1, None]).max(axis=0)
    outbound = np.clip(np.maximum(o1, o2), a_max=None, a_min=0)
    rez = 1000000 * outbound.max()
    return rez
```

Comment: Do you have some example data, preferably an amount that is enough to reproduce it's slowness?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6g5DWhZd

Comment: Please amend it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting to perform the outbound elementwise function call in one go, and of course use `np.max()` instead of comparing `y` to `mx` in a for loop:

```
import numpy as np


def outbound_penalty(x, bs):
    o1 = (bs[:, 0] - x).max()
    o2 = (x - bs[:, 1]).max()
    outbound = max(o1, o2, 0)
    return 1000000 * outbound


def outbound_penalty_fast(x, bs):
    o1 = (bs[:, 0, None] - x).max(axis=0)
    o2 = (x - bs[:, 1, None]).max(axis=0)
    outbound = np.clip(np.maximum(o1, o2), a_max=None, a_min=0)
    return 1000000 * outbound


bnd = np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(2, 2))
bnd[:, 0] = 0
sss = np.random.uniform(-100, 300, size=(2, 1000))

%timeit np.max(np.array([outbound_penalty(x, bnd) for x in sss.T]))
# 9.44 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.max(outbound_penalty_fast(sss, bnd))
# 38.1 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

mx = np.max(np.array([outbound_penalty(x, bnd) for x in sss.T]))
mx_fast = np.max(outbound_penalty_fast(sss, bnd))

mx == mx_fast  # True
```

Comment: I am sorry, for this misunderstanding. Actually all outer loop with mx doesnt matter. It is a rudimentary habbit, from previous language with too optimizing compiler.

Comment: What does matter - %timeit outbound_penalty(x, bnd)

Comment: The whole idea was to remove the outer loop, so why are you running `[outbound_penalty_fast(x, np_bounds) for x in smpls]` and not `outbound_penalty_fast(sss, np_bounds)`?

Comment: Cause %timeit makes such a lot of work for me, so I still cant believe it ))))

Comment: Even after your latest change, you are still running `outbound_penalty_fast()` on one sample. You are supposed to **run it on all samples**!

Comment: Okay, give me ten minutes, I profile the main minimization task with both  outbound_penalty_fast and outbound_penalty

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt understand that outbound_penalty_fast() returns np.array, not a single float point number as outbound_penalty().

Comment: So I have to change it, to fit result to expected value.            def outbound_penalty_fast(x, bs):
            o1 = (bs[:, 0, None] - x).max(axis=0)
            o2 = (x - bs[:, 1, None]).max(axis=0)
            outbound = np.clip(np.maximum(o1, o2), a_max=None, a_min=0)
            rez = 1000000 * outbound.max()
            return rez

Comment: Th results is 76492 ms Own Time for outbound_penalty_fast() in 5019484 calls. Versus 36480 ms Own Time for outbound_penalty() in 4127323 calls. It is not clear for my, why calls count is not the same. Probably function returns different penalties for outbound, and minimize trajectory is also different. I have to check it

Comment: Well, you give `outbound_penalty()` one sample and it returns one value. You give `outbound_penalty_fast()` `N` samples and it returns `N` values.

Comment: No. outbound_penalty(x, bnds) takes one n-dim point x, and one n-dim rectangular bounds. I cant vectorize it, cause it calls from inside scipy.optimize.minimize(method='Nelder-Mead')

Comment: Well, then create a new question that details this.